# Do cycles have their own stack record? (aka why is this code legal)

Tags: c, variables, while-loop, scope, logic

Ok, so I'm having a little question for you here.

I'm going to write code in C, but I guess this would work just the same in most languages.

So, why is this code legal:

```
int x = 1;
while(true) {
    int x = x + 2;
}
```

While this calls for **error: redefinition of ‘x’**

```
int x = 1;
int x = 3;
```

So, I am aware that I'd be able to use the same name for a variabile in different functions within my program, since each function call would have its own stack record.

But do cycles have their own stack records as well? On a memory level, code #1 doesn't result in me having N different associactions for the variable x within the same stack record block?

In short, why in code #2 I'm redefining the x variable, but in code #1 I am not?

Comment: Variable names don't exist in the machine code. The compiler knows that, within the while, and after `x` is declared, using `x` refers to the second one. It's a new, smaller scope, but there is typically no new stack frame.

Comment: Blocks (and so loop bodies) have their own *scope*. And please use this generic term instead of *stack*, because *stack* is just one of the way to implement things.

Comment: So one could assimilate function calls to loops, when it comes to variable scopes? Like, initializing a loop creates a new environment, as it would happen with a function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two variables are declared in different scope.

```
int x = 1;
while(true) {
    int x = x + 2;
}
```

The variable declared in the inner scope hides the variable declared in the outer scope.

Pay attention to that this declaration

```
int x = x + 2;
```

has undefined behavior because the declared variable is used itself as an initializer though it was not initialized.

For example you can write

```
int x = 1;

int main( void )
{
   int x = 2;

   while ( 1 )
   {
      int x = 3;
      /*...*/
   }
}
```

In this program there are declared and defined three different objects with the name `x`.

The first variable has the file scope while the other two have block scopes.

As for this code snippet

```
int x = 1;
int x = 3;
```

two variables in the same scope are defined with the same name.

In C (but not in C++) you may write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;
int x = 1;

int main(void) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

because in the file scope this

```
int x;
```

is not a definition of the variable x but is only its declaration.

Also you may write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;
int x = 1;

int main(void) 
{
    extern int x;

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );

    return 0;
}
```

The line

```
    extern int x;
```

introduces the declaration of the global variable `x` in the block scope of main.

As for the while statement then (The C STandard, 6.8.5 Iteration statements
)

> 5 An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of
>   the scope of its enclosing block. The loop body is also a block whose
>   scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement.

Comment: Thank you a lot. So would it be correct if I said that a cycle has its own scope, in the same way that a function does?

Comment: `int x;` at file scope is a tentative definition.

Comment: @MichaelVigato: Not quite. Each *block* has its own scope. A block is a sequence of statements inside braces, `{ … }`. The scope you associate with a function is in fact a block scope, delimited by the main braces for the function. A loop (not commonly called a cycle) does not have its own scope, but many loops are written with a block, which does have its own scope. For example, in `while (x) x--;`, there is no new scope, because there is no block. But in `while (x) { x--; }`, there is a new scope.